# Spark 2: How to filter multiple ranges from a dataframe

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge dataframe from which I need to filter rows corresponding to multiple ranges. I have tried following two approaches and both of them are extremely slow because the dataframe is too huge and is backed by hbase(using [shc](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) library).

1. Chain multiple filter conditions.
   where ((key >= range1.start && key <=range1.end) || (key >= range2.start && key <=range2.end) || ... )
2. Create a scanRanges dataframe from the ranges list, then create temp views for both data and scans

   allRecords.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
      scanRanges.createOrReplaceTempView("scans")

   Now I run this query

   sqlContext.sql("select * from data, scans where data.col0 between scans._1 and scans._2").show(20)

I have even tried broadcasting scan table but that doesn't help. I need to avoid join completely and be able to filter the records to avoid scanning them on hbase. Is it possible?

E.g.:
Data table (truncated)

```
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------+----+
|  col0| col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|          col7|col8|
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------+----+
|row000| true| 0.0| 0.0|   0|   0|   0| String0 extra|   0|
|row001|false| 1.0| 1.0|   1|   1|   1| String1 extra|   1|
|row002| true| 2.0| 2.0|   2|   2|   2| String2 extra|   2|
|row003|false| 3.0| 3.0|   3|   3|   3| String3 extra|   3|
```

Scan table

```
+------+------+
|_1    |_2    |
+------+------+
|row020|row024|
|row030|row034|
|row040|row044|
|row046|row049|
+------+------+
```

Result (truncated)

```
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------+----+
|col0  |col1 |col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7          |col8|
+------+-----+----+----+----+----+----+--------------+----+
|row043|false|43.0|43.0|43  |43  |43  |String43 extra|43  |
|row042|true |42.0|42.0|42  |42  |42  |String42 extra|42  |
|row044|true |44.0|44.0|44  |44  |44  |String44 extra|44  |
|row030|true |30.0|30.0|30  |30  |30  |String30 extra|30  |
|row048|true |48.0|48.0|48  |48  |48  |String48 extra|48  |
|row024|true |24.0|24.0|24  |24  |24  |String24 extra|24  |
```